# Magento2: How to move product tabs to short description area

Tags: magento2

I want to move tabs:

- description
- more information
- reviews

to short description area. Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to create `catalog_product_view.xml.`

If you have a custom theme, create **catalog_product_view.xml** at

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

If you have a custom module, create **catalog_product_view.xml** at

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

**1.Description**

```
<move element="product.info.details" destination="product.info.overview" after="-"/>
```

**2. More Information**

```
<move element=”product.attributes” destination="product.info.overview" after="-"/>
```

> > **NOTE:-** It will move attributes visible in `More Information` tab to product details section and will be shown below product details.

Check this link :- **https://pagayo.com/blog/magento-2-move-more-information-below-main-description/**

**3. Reviews**

```
<move element="reviews.tab" destination="product.info.overview" after="-" />
```

Hope this help you

Thanks ...